# Is a better way to declear this return type of an array transform function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I has a function that help me to write code easy,

```
const TASKS = valueMap([
    { id: -1, key: 'all', name: 'all-task' },
    { id: 1, key: 'editing', name: 'editing-task' },
    { id: 2, key: 'done', name: 'done-task' },
]);

// any values of object can be use to access the object
console.log(TASKS[-1]); // { id: -1, key: 'all', name: 'all-task' }
console.log(TASKS['all']); // { id: -1, key: 'all', name: 'all-task' }
console.log(TASKS['all-task']); // { id: -1, key: 'all', name: 'all-task' }
console.log(TASKS['not-exist']); // undefined
// and so on...
```

here is the function implementation in typescript:

```
const valueMap = <T extends { [key: string]: any; }>(arr: T[]) => {
    return arr.reduce((ret: { [key: string]: T; }, values) => {
        Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
            ret[values[key]] = values;
        });
        return ret;
    }, {});
};
```

the funciton is good, but the return types is not, is there any way to make this an error in typescript?

```
console.log(TASKS['not-exist']) // key Error
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your function does what it's suposed to do. All of your `console.log()` statements will print `undefined`.

Comment: This sounds very weird. It'd make more sense if each object was constrained to just one key.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry, it toke a mistake, i fix it just now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem. Both have drawbacks.

**Solution 1**: Here you have to define the shape of the array elements passed to `valueMap`.

```
const valueMap = <
  T extends { id: ID, key: KEY, name: NAME }[], 
  ID extends number, 
  KEY extends string, 
  NAME extends string
>(arr: [...T]): Record<T[number][keyof T[number]] & (string | number), T[number]> => {
    return arr.reduce((ret: any, values: any) => {
        Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
            ret[values[key]] = values;
        });
        return ret;
    }, {});
};
```

The biggest challenge here is type inference. TypeScript will rarely infer the types of strings or numbers as narrowly as we need here. So normally when you pass an object to a function like `{ a: 123 }`, TypeScript will infer it as `{ a: number }`. To force TypeScript to narrow down the types we have to use some tricks.

The first one is the spread operator for `arr` => `arr: [...T]`. This will force TypeScript to infer the passed array as a tuple. Then we have to define a generic type for the shape of the passed array `T` and additional generic types for each property `ID`, `KEY` and `NAME`.

The return type will be `Record<T[number][keyof T[number]] & (string | number), T[number]>`.

Now we get an error when wrongly indexing `TASKS`:

```
const TASKS = valueMap([
    { id: -1, key: 'all', name: 'all-task' },
    { id: 1, key: 'editing', name: 'editing-task' },
    { id: 2, key: 'done', name: 'done-task' },
]);


console.log(TASKS[-1]);
console.log(TASKS['all']);
console.log(TASKS['all-task']);
console.log(TASKS['not-exist']); // Error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=20&pln=21&pc=21#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIBuBDANgVwKYFlkAd4BeeAHmHngBV5MAPWTSAE2ngCdNkmpUBPeAEqYIbJiThsAlpADmAGnjJIvAHwBtALoLgKgBTI2bAFxUAlCaEixlNZHQBbAEaY2GtQGtMvcADMqth2dXDXgAMnhdCWkZeAAfeDsnF1MFG0SgjRUiLIBvcgp2TFh0NkhFQwA6DiZ0UExdXQ5YEyVeBRQMTGgW5VNs+DyCofgAeUcAK2FYCs9eaF0OrGhTCp9wNgBRZFAACwbZvsJc-OHhprVFro8vDRDiS+gAbhPhgF9TZ9OKJpKyps+Cq8FDl3s9Xs8wFA4FQAIIAZQA0nCiEg0FhcHhdGoXjl4JImCYALQARgUsxMAHI0KgKQpIMh7JhKdTCbBkNB3BT4ECcXiCfBSfByfAKZgmJJYNFaQkGUyRWKJdFWezOdy5Lz8SYAExkryU7iQTDS+mM-VQTDKjlcnkhdnwCAwWAfECQmDgVCYCqocAyXSUeFItQkjTOh3Qd2e72+-2IuFqKmoGkh55hiNen1+gNxhOoS2c5Ou8Me9PRrPxyDgWCEuiSOAU5PwAD0jfgG0M61bHsZkAQknseFQklAEr48B2dqUItaXNgvDwmHgzlAyHQ0AX0iYdBotDwHGg0EkUDxrArCF88Fn85F6RcFIqQA)

---

**Solution 2**: The second solution is more flexible in the shape of the objects inside the array but we have to use `as const`.

```
const valueMap = <
  T extends readonly Record<string, any>[], 
>(arr: T): Record<T[number][keyof T[number]] & string | number, T[number]> => {
    return arr.reduce((ret: any, values: any) => {
        Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
            ret[values[key]] = values;
        });
        return ret;
    }, {});
};

const TASKS = valueMap([
    { id: -1, key: 'all', name: 'all-task' },
    { id: 1, key: 'editing', name: 'editing-task' },
    { id: 2, key: 'done', name: 'done-task' },
] as const); // <-- as const here


console.log(TASKS[-1]);
console.log(TASKS['all']);
console.log(TASKS['all-task']);
console.log(TASKS['not-exist']); // Error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=129&pln=3&pc=1#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%20v0xuOoc3sxPO0Nu1ORjOxyDgWD4uiSOBkxPwAD09fga0Mq2bbvpkAQknseFQklAYr48C2NqUQuaHNgvDwmHgzlAyHQ0Dn0iYdBotDwHGg0EkUBxrDLCF88Gns6FqRcZLKQA)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. I prefer the second way, it's perfect with my code. But a more question please, is the part `& string | number` of the return type nessecary??